# In Java, is the immutability of Strings considered in the implementation of String.format()?

Tags: java, string, memory, immutability, string-formatting

Since Strings in Java are immutable, I've always used StringBuilder or StringBuffer to concatenate Strings.  Does the String.format() method handle this issue as well as StringBuilder or StringBuffer?  In other words, does String.format() manage memory as well as StringBuffer or StringBuilder?

Comment: (1) This is implementation-specific. (2) It works well enough untill you have data that shows it doesn't work well enough, regardless of how it's acutally implemented. (3) As hinted in 2, and as *always* with such questions, the only way to make sure is to profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the source code of Oracle JDK, it seems that the implementation creates a new `Formatter` for each `String#format` call which in turn allocates a fresh `StringBuilder` for each call. So yes. But as mentioned by the comment to your question, this is very much implementation specific though common sense entails that it would choose the most efficient way of doing things.

Comment: Interesting, thanks!  So as a follow-up, since StringBuilder is not thread-safe, I would assume String.format() is also not thread-safe... at least the Oracle implementation?

Comment: If each call to format creates a new StringBuilder and keeps it local to the method, then the call to format can still be thread safe.

Comment: @Michael "Can still be thread safe"?  It sounds like you're implying that the developer can make it thread-safe by calling String.format() in a thread-safe manner.  Clearly.  Maybe I'm not being clear.  The followup, as well as the original question was regarding the implementation of String.format().  So my followup would be better posed as "Since the implementation of String.format() depends on StringBuilder in the oracle implementation, and since we know that StringBuilder is NOT thread-safe, does that mean that the implementation of String.format() in oracle's jdk is also not thread-safe?"

Comment: @fooMonster: The most important concept here is not about mutability or immutability of `StringBuilder` but about the "visibility" of the newly created `StringBuilder`. `String.format` creates a new `Formatter()` which is only visible to the thread which called this method (since it is a "local"/method scoped variable) which in turn implies that the `StringBuilder` created by the formatter is also only visible to the calling thread. This is the reason why String.format() is thread safe. It doesn't involve any instance level variables when executing the method call. :-)

Comment: @fooMonster The reason I said "may be thread safe" is because I didn't look at the code, and the documentation does mention thread safety.  Sanjay did a great job of explaining how it would still be thread safe.

Comment: @Sanjay Excellent!  Thank you very much.  For the record, immutability/memory was the original question, thread safety was the followup.  You all have reminded me, however, that I can grab the oracle source so I can answer these for myself from now on!  :-)  Much Thanks!